# IEnumerable serialize as [JsonObject] in Json.NET, without using the attribute

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I want to serialize an IEnumerable as a JsonObject, like the way it gets serialized by applying the [JsonObject] attribute, but I cannot change the DTO classes by introducing this attribute.

Is there a way to tell the (de)serializer to force JsonObject (de)serialization?

Comment: Please provide example of your class and json you want to serialize it to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a custom `IContractResolver` to do this.  All you need to do is create a resolver class deriving from Json.Net's `DefaultContractResolver` and override the `CreateContract(Type)` method as shown below, where `FooList` is replaced with the type of your enumerable.

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(FooList))
            return CreateObjectContract(typeof(FooList));

        return base.CreateContract(type);
    }
}
```

Add the resolver to the serializer settings and use those settings when you serialize:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(),
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, settings);
```

Here is a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ocyjU4

Comment: Very cool and exactly what I needed. The example was spot on, I actually wanted a list with extra metadata to serialize as object :-)